# gscript file.getAs('text/plain') gets sever errror

Tags: server-error

I am trying to take a csv file loaded into Google Drive and convert it into a GSheet so I can use the data. Unfortunately, I cannot share the file since it contains sensitive information. I did find out the encoding type is "markbook.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii" but every time I run this script:

```html
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1RcM3d-Eg-qjacW7Uqg8iVW8xJew-TD-3");
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getAs('text/plain'));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet("Sheet13");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  
}
```

Google responds with a server error. I tried 'us-ascii', .getAs() and even just file.getBlob(); but they still all replied with a server error.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- `getAs()` cannot use the mimeType of `text/plain`.
- In order to retrieve string data from blob, you can use `getDataAsString()`.
- In order to import csv data to the sheet with the sheet name of "Sheet13", you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet13")`.

  - For this modification, since I thought that you might want to import CSV to the sheet, I modified like this. If you need other patterns, please tell me.

The modified script which reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1RcM3d-Eg-qjacW7Uqg8iVW8xJew-TD-3");
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); // Modified
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet13"); // Modified
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

#### Note :

- This modified script supposes that you use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. If you want to use standalone script. Please tell me. I would like to modify it.

#### References :

- [getAs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))
- [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getdataasstring)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but the server error still happens. I found some sites that mention the encoding of the csv file could be a problem but mine is a different encoding. I don't know if this a script error or a GScript quirk which I'm running into more and more.

Comment: @Mr. M. Perzan I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about your situation? Is the file text data of csv? Also you can see the retrieved data from the file using ``Logger.log(file.getBlob().getDataAsString())``. And can you try to use the script using a sample csv file? By this, I think it may find the problem of your csv file. When you tell the result, I would like to think of the other solution from it.

Comment: @Mr. M. Perzan Or can you provide us a sample csv which has the same format of the csv file you want to use? Of course, please change the values from original one.